# Wire sizing from breaker box to bedroom

Tags: electrical

If you were wiring a bedroom and a new house and you ran a 12-2  for your homerun and then to each outlet receptacle in the room let’s say there were four.  Then from the last outlet receptacle you ran 12-2  up to the bedroom light switch outlet.  At that point you switch to 14-2  and ran it up to the lights. Would that be permissible if you used a 15 amp breaker?  Wouldn’t it be possible that someone could later change the 15 to 20  amp breaker not knowing about the 14-2 to the light.

Comment: I'll take "things my electrician did that were stupid but technically permissible" for $200, Alex.

Answer (score 2):

A 15A breaker (AFCI) is not just permissible in this situation, it is required because of the #14 wire in the circuit. You should make a note somewhere near the panel indicating that circuit has #14 wire in it and to not replace the 15A breaker with a 20A. Alternatively - and this is the much preferred way to do things - just use #12 throughout and put a 20A breaker on.

However, if at all possible, keep your receptacles and lights on different circuits. If you trip a breaker you won't be left in the dark!

Comment: I like keeping the lights on separate circuits also but it is bad practice to change wire size. If you want to only run 1 circuit run everything in 12 and use a 20 amp breaker.

Comment: @EdBeal bad practice, but allowed nonetheless. I edited to emphasize using #12 throughout is the preferred method.